# the interest comes in

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> **At a bank**
> Teller: *"Well, let's see... this money that you're depositing comes to almost $100."*
> Boy: *"Right"*.
> Teller: *"So, if you put this into a savings account and save it for several months, we have the use of your money for those months."*
> Boy: *"Oh, so you borrow my money for several months."*
> Teller: *"Yes, but that's where the interest **comes in**, because we pay you for lending us your money. We pay you interest."*

---

What does *"the interest **comes in**"* mean?

Comment: What is the Source of this conversation, please

Answer (score 2):

***That's where the xxxx comes in*** is an informal way of introducing a new concept or object in a conversation where it's relevant but hasn't been mentioned before.

> But how will we cross the river when we get there?
>
> Ah, that's where the raft comes in.

The teller is trying to explain to the boy why depositing the money is a good idea, so s/he introduces the concept of interest. (The interest is the money being paid on the balance (the amount deposited). So if you deposit $100 at 1 %, at some point you'll get the interest of $1 added on.)

Comment: Thank you, fev. I want to know what does "comes in" exactly mean in this sentence. Does it mean "be received"?

Comment: No, it's more literal than that. It has exactly the same meaning as it does in "it comes into the room" only in this case, rather than coming into the room, it's coming into the *conversation*.

It's talking about interest as a concept or idea, rather than any actual money.

I can edit this into the answer if it makes more sense to you? Like Kate says, "becomes relevant" is an alternative.

Comment: I deleted my comment (having accidentally hit return before I'd finished it) when I saw that you had replied!